# What is the correct way of using document.querySelectorAll in CapserJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape HTML links for different pages from a website using CasperJS.

In my browser address bar (Firefox/Chrome), this works perfectly fine and opens all links that I'm looking for.

```
javascript:document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/page"]').click();
```

However, when I try to run something similar on CasperJS using the below code, I get a lot of errors which aren't consistent with the above.

```
var pageNodes = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/page"]');
});

console.log(typeof(pageNodes)); //Shows object
console.log(pageNodes.length); //Shows 11, which is correct

var links = [];

for(var i = 0; i < pageNodes.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(pageNodes[i].href);
    links.push(pageNodes[i].href);
}; //pageNode[0].href shows the correct link. pageNode[1] is a null for some reason when it shouldn't be!
```

I also tried Array prototyping on the above, but with the same results! Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong?

```
var pageArray = this.evaluate(function(pageNodes) {
    return Array.prototype.splice(pageNodes, 0);
}); //Gives the same problem, since pagesNodes[1] is null.
```

Comment: You're missing a closing paren on line #3

Comment: Oops. Typo while typing the question. The problem still remains....

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS has two contexts and since CasperJS is built on top of it, it has the same limitation. It means that the access to the page context is sandboxed and you can't pass arbitrary objects around. The [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) says this:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

If you want to access the href property of every link then you have to built a primitive object that can be passed outside or just print from the page context:

```
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
    this.echo("remote> " + msg);
});
var links = this.evaluate(function() {
    var pageNodes = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/page"]');
    var links = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < pageNodes.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(pageNodes[i].href);
        links.push(pageNodes[i].href);
    };
    return links;
});
require("utils").dump(links);
```

Comment: I tried this - converted it to an Array, but still didn't work! What am I missing? function getLinks(selector) { var pageLinks = document.querySelectorAll(selector); return Array.prototype.map.call(pageLinks, function(e) { return e.getAttribute('href'); }); } casper.then(function() { pages = this.evaluate(getLinks, 'a'); require('utils').dump(pages); //pages is still null here, no idea why! });

Comment: Make sure the page is loaded by taking a screenshot (`casper.capture(filename)`). Also, please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.